# Find the sum of $\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+m)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

First, the series is absolutely convergent since

$$\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+m)!}\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m!}=2e-2$$

I don't know how to find the sum though. Any hints?

Comment: That inequality is not true. At least, not obviously.

Comment: It should be the product, not the sum, with upper bound thus $(e-1)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one way to get $n+m=2$ for $n\ge 1,m\ge 1$, namely $n=m=1$. There are two ways to get $n+m=3$, namely $n=1,m=2$ and $n=2,m=1$. There are three ways to get $n+m=4$, and so on. Rearranging your sum to group identical values of $n+m=k$ gives

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{k-1}{k!}$$

Can you continue from there?

Comment: $\sum_{k=2}\frac{k-1}{k!}=\sum_{k=2}\frac{1}{k-1!}-\sum_{k=2}\frac{1}{k!}=e-1-e+2=1$?

Comment: @luka5z: Yep, that looks right. I also confirmed it numerically in two different ways.

Answer (score 3):

There are $k-1$ terms where $m+n=k$.

---

For the upper bound use that $\binom{m+n}{n}\ge 1$, so that 
$$
\frac1{(m+n)!}\le\frac1{m!}·\frac1{n!}
$$
so that this upper bound can be separated into the square of $(e-1)$.